# Problem running Gitlab with unbound Nginx and Wordpress in Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm trying to setup Gitlab and Wordpress together with Nginx in Docker. I can only publish ports 80 and 443 which is why I wanted to use an unbound Nginx to map the ports published in docker to (sub) URLs.
I can access Wordpress by the domain-name with ssl and I'm also able to access other docker-containers with suburls, but I can't access Gitlab. I've tried multiple Nginx and Gitlab settings such as turning on/ off Gitlabs own Nginx and different values for `external_url` in `gitlab.rb` but I only got it halfway working with the following setup. However everytime I try to login I get redirected to wordpress with the url being something like `my.domain.com/users/sign_in`

This is my setup:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  git:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.10.0-ce.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: 'my.domain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
         external_url 'http://127.0.0.1:8929/'
    ports:
      - "8929:80"
      - "2224:22"
    shm_size: '256m'
```

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name my.domain.com www.my.domain.com;


  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    allow all;
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }


  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  root /var/www/html;

  index index.php;

  server_name my.domain.com www.my.domain.com;

  server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;


  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

# WORDPRESS
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on wordpress:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
# GITLAB
  location /gitlab/ {
    gzip                    off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8929/;
  }
}
```

The goal would be something like this:

```
my.domain.com                 -> Wordpress        -> (directly setup together with nginx, therefore no ports published by wordpress-service)
my.domain.com/gitlab          -> Gitlab           -> Docker-Port: 8929:80, 2224:22
my.domain.com/something-else  -> Something-Else   -> Docker-Port: 9000:9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting everything and doing a new setup I actually got it running, with slightly different settings:

docker-compose Gitlab:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  git:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.10.0-ce.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: 'my.domain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
         external_url 'http://<host-ip-address>:<docker-gitlab-port>/gitlab/'
    ports:
      - "8929:8929" #doesn't work with 8929:80; no clue why though
      - "2224:2224"
    volumes:
      - /opt/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:rw
      - /opt/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:rw
    shm_size: '256m'
```

nginx.conf changes

```
location /gitlab/ {
    root /home/git/gitlab/public;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://<host-ip-address>:<docker-gitlab-port>/gitlab/;

    gzip                    off;

    #proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host; ##This one crashes everything (?)
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://<host-ip-address>:<docker-gitlab-port>/gitlab/'
```